# Billing address form missing in checkout since upgrade to Magento 2.4.4

Tags: onepage-checkout, billing-address, magento2.4.4, missing

since upgrading my Magento instance from 2.4.3 to 2.4.4, the onepage checkout is missing the form for the billing address.

After unchecking the checkbox for "same as shipping address", the address simply disappears without showing the form as before.

[image: before checking the checkbox]

[image: after checking the checkbox]

I removed all corresponding layout files (Magento_Checkout) for the used theme, but the problem still persists.

Did anybody come across this error and find a fix for this?

**UPDATE**
After fiddling around mit some Third Party Modules and my own stuff - thanks to Tu Van - it turned out, that one of my own modules was defect and causing the billing address form from showing.

So if you ever come across this, check first, if you implemented a defect address validator (like in my case) or installed a broken module.

Thanks in advance,
Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some JS/html/PHP files from your theme or custom modules, 3rd-party modules override the Magento_Checkout module that causes the issue.
Let's run this command to check if any JS/html/PHP files override the Magento_Checkout module: `grep -r Magento_Checkout app vendor`.

Do you use the Magento checkout default module or another 3rd-party module?

Comment: Yep - I also thought of a theme error at first, but then 4 themes should be broken. I switched to Luma, but the problem still exists. I am using the default Magento Onepage Checkout

Comment: Let's run the command and check the result first.

Comment: Grepping for Magento_Checkout in app and vendor prints 1.100 lines -> that does not really help.

Comment: Ok, so you should split it into commands smaller. Due to you using the Magento checkout default module, you can ignore grepping `vendor/magento`.  Try with commands: 1. `grep -r Magento_Checkout app/code`. 2. `grep -r Magento_Checkout app/design` then investigate the result. After investigating you didn't detect which files caused the issue yet, you should continue grepping the 3rd-party modules in vendor.

Comment: An update, I think some JS or html files caused this error, not PHP files.

Comment: Thanks. It has indeed been a third party module.
After disabling a bunch of modules, the form shows up again - now I'll need to re-enable all that stuff to hit the module, causing that error.

Comment: Great. that would be great if you edit your post to write the third party module that causes this error then others who have the same issue can easily find the solution.